# How to make number of visibleSlides responsive in CSS in pure-react-carousel

Tags: pure-react-carousel

How/can we make number of visibleSlides responsive in CSS? / not have to use JS to alter `visibleSlides` based on breakpoints.

**For example;** 
Each slide has   `min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px;` ie. image we want to see detail so shouldn't be smaller than 100px.

We set `visibleSlides` to 8 (for desktop). On mobile we want to show only 2 slides. Because we don't want the individual slides to be less than 100px height and width, nor have the slides overlapping.

I know we could use react to check screen width and set `visibleSlides`, however it's not easy for all apps to have access to this, especially server side rendered like next.js.

See this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pure-react-carousel-responsive-visible-slides-k8cui

*(Forked from https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-wood-4bx36?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)*

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem for my app and actually couldn't find a way to do this with `CSS`. However, I've implemented this using `ResizeObserver` and `react-hooks`. 
P.S. I'm using `next js`, and it's not a big issue to implement it on the server-side. 
 
Here's my solution, hope it could help. 
Step 1. Create an observer hook to listen for resize events from the app.

```js
import { useEffect, useState, RefObject } from 'react';
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';

interface DOMRectReadOnly {
  readonly bottom: number;
  readonly height: number;
  readonly left: number;
  readonly right: number;
  readonly top: number;
  readonly width: number;
  readonly x: number;
  readonly y: number;
}

interface useResizeObserverProperties {
  ref?: RefObject<Element> | null;

  element?: Element | null | undefined;

  callback?: (entry: ResizeObserverEntry) => void;
}

const IS_BROWSER = typeof window !== 'undefined';

/**
 * Watch for the resizing of a React component or Element.
 *
 * @param hookProperties - Configuration optinos for the hook.
 *
 * @returns The `DOMRect` for the observed element.
 */
export const useResizeObserver = ({
  ref,
  element,
  callback,
}: useResizeObserverProperties) => {
  const [sizes, setSizes] = useState<DOMRectReadOnly>({
    bottom: 0,
    height: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });

  const handleResize = (entries: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
    const [entry] = entries;

    if (callback) callback(entry);

    setSizes(entry.contentRect);
  };

  const [resizeObs] = useState(() =>
    IS_BROWSER ? new ResizeObserver(handleResize) : undefined,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!resizeObs) return;
    let domNode;

    if (ref) {
      domNode = ref.current;
    } else if (element) {
      domNode = element;
    }

    if (domNode) {
      resizeObs.observe(domNode);
    }

    return () => resizeObs.disconnect();
  }, [ref, resizeObs, element]);

  return sizes;
};
```

Step 2. In your `component.tsx`

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { CarouselProvider, Slider, Slide } from 'pure-react-carousel';
import { useResizeObserver } from 'from previously created file';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [visibleSlides, setVisibleSlides] = useState(1);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  // Current width of element
  const { width } = useResizeObserver({ ref });

  switch (true) {
    case width > 768 && width < 1280:
      setVisibleSlides(2);
      break;
    /**
     * Switch your cases here
     */
  }

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <CarouselProvider
        naturalSlideWidth={100}
        naturalSlideHeight={125}
        totalSlides={3}
        visibleSlides={visibleSlides}
      >
        <Slider>
          <Slide index={0}>Slide 1</Slide>
          <Slide index={1}>Slide 2</Slide>
          <Slide index={2}>Slide 3</Slide>
        </Slider>
      </CarouselProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Btw I'll recommend you `throttle` `setVisibleSlides` calls to avoid too much re-renders while resizing the window from dev-tools.

Comment: You never had the issue of having ref.current to null during first render?

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, but i'm trying to do the same. 
How about using React hooks `useState` for the `visibleSlides` integer, and creating a window listener that listens for breakpoints and changes the state as needed....

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a state and using useEffect to update the state on resize of window, then passing down the window size as a prop to the carousel component and choosing the number of visibleslides using the prop?

https://codesandbox.io/s/pure-react-carousel-responsive-visible-slides-forked-q29c1d?file=/src/App.js